# Well developed web site architecture using linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, architecture

Anybody found yet a good web site architecture using linq to sql? Any help will be very helpful!

Comment: in about 4 months from now I should be able to show you one =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just finished up an internal IT project banking heavily on Linq2Sql and it paid off.   I was a bit skeptical at first, but I think it worked out great in the end.  Just remember, the fundamentals don't change.

1. try to stay as stateless as possible
2. keep clean lines between your services and data access
3. don't **fight** linq, **use** it.  If it isn't helping you, you are probably doing something wrong

Our implementation ended up being a hybrid of the [Andrew Siemer](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115232305/http://geekswithblogs.net/AndrewSiemer/archive/2008/02/05/linq-to-sql---implementing-the-repository-pattern.aspx) and [Beth Massi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/) approach (a bit heavier on the Andrew side) and in C#

Comment: +1: Great answer. This helped me a lot. I was trying to find a smart way to implement an n-tier architecture using L2S, and these solutions accomplish that eloquently.

Comment: I would love to hear what you ended up using that is heavier on my side!  :)

Comment: @andrew-siemer it has been 6 years but if memory serves it was mostly your connection management style.

Answer (score 2):

What, apart from StackOverflow?   ;-)

Comment: is the source code available? :P

Answer (score 1):

Remember Linq is a technology that sits atop the typical data access structures. Therefore all rules that have applied thus far still hold. Just because you can get to data a little easier in the client app doesnt mean you throw out the architecture best practices for data access.

Answer (score 1):

[Rob Conery's MVC Storefront](http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples)

As others have said, linq-to-sql is no different to any other ORM so the architecture is the same as you would use for NHibernate and others.

Comment: I haven't looked too far into the code, but it looks like something that was thrown together in an evening.  There's  a SQL statements right in the index.aspx of the home page, and it's not even using Linq To SQL.

Comment: Rob's project would be using Subsonic rather then linq to SQL